# Image, texts and button alignment must not change based on window size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a website and for the landing page, I need to build something like below as a first section.

[image]

but it looks like this

[image]

and

[image]

when resizing

The code is this one :

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeCurated from '../components/sections/HomeCuratedSection';
import HomeTrend from '../components/sections/HomeTrendSection';
import NearbyYou from '../components/sections/HomeNearbySection';

import VillageBanner from '../assets/images/village-banner-icon.png';
import DiscoverImage from '../assets/images/discover-home.jpg';
import WhiteButton from '../components/materialdesign/WhiteButton';
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';


import './Home.css';

class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="discover-tile">
                    <div className="background">
                    <img
                        src= { DiscoverImage }
                        className= "background"
                        alt="Village"
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div className="text-tile">
                            <h1>{TextContents.ThinkOfUs}</h1>
                            <p>{TextContents.TheWorldIsYours}</p>
                            <div className="button">
                                <WhiteButton textSize="14" link_href="/discover" text={TextContents.DiscoverBtn} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <img
                            src= { VillageBanner }
                            className = "banner"
                            alt="Village"
                        />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                );
        }
}

export default Home;
```

and css :

```
.discover-tile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 657px;
    border-radius: 21.5px;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 657px;
    border-radius: 21.5px;
}

.text-tile {
    width: 370px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align-last: left;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20%;
    right: 0;
}

.text-tile h1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 370px;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 39px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.text-tile p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    top: 28%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffffff;
}

.banner {
    width: 54px;
    height: 82px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 15%; 
    right: 0;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 32%;
}
```

Any idea how to make sure the style/position of text remain the same when changing the screen or at leat adapt a little ?

Comment: Absolute positions are not very good when want it to dynamically adjust; but you can probably use media Query and do some more positioning but i will not recommend using absolute position; or you can probably try grid lay out it is pretty easy to get started with grids.

Comment: Also the issue is your width is 100%; so when you reduce window width all components are shrunk horizontally; except the text which has fixed width and takes up a lot of space; While Image has a fixed vertical height which also keep the original image height while the width is shrunk

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava any advice on how to properly do it ? I am an Android dev so I am usually using `dp` instead of pixel any equivalent on react ?

Comment: Grid layout is easiest to start with handling different resolutions; so basically when you go from landscape to portrait you can just add a media query and say now i want my grid to be different. Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout it has all basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to add Media query into the end of css file and you should apply `position:absolute` only on `.text-tile`' container not it's descendants, because the container `.text-tile` is on absolute position already, so you just add/change margin/padding property if you want to change space of it's descendants (here is h1 and p). You can take a look on this article for more information about grid table: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp. I don't know if this code work for you or not, you should try this:

```css
.discover-tile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 657px;
    border-radius: 21.5px;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 657px;
    border-radius: 21.5px;
}

.text-tile {
    width: 370px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align-last: left;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20%;
    right: 0;
}

/* change position:absolute -> position:relative for your desktop version */
.text-tile h1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 370px;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 39px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.text-tile p {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    /* with relative position property, it's naturally lay next to each other, so now if you just need to add padding/margin to h1 and p for spacing  
    top: 28%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;  */
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffffff;
}
/* tablet, ipad  version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .text-tile h1 {
        font-size: 34px;
    }
    .text-tile p {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
/* mobile version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .text-tile, .text-tile h1, .text-tile p{
        width: calc(100% - 20%); /* subtract the left:20% of .text-tile in desktop-version  and set full width */
    }
    .text-tile h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .text-tile p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="discover-tile">
  <div class="background">
    <img
         src= "https://via.placeholder.com/720"
         class= "background"
         alt="Village"
         />
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="text-tile">
      <h1>Think of us as smart friend that takes you to do cool stuff</h1>
      <p>The world is yours</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>
          Discover
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes needed, but the biggest mistake you have done here is using these two css rules together,

```
width: 100%;
height: 657px;
```

If you set the with to 100%, it would fit the viewport, but the height is fixed. So, on all smaller screens, the width would get less, but the height would still remain the same. This will not conserve the aspect ratio of the image, and thus the image would be stretched vertically. Which is clear in the question images.

The fix for this, if you want a full width image is too set

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Now, the image height would auto adjust and the image won't be distorted. Once you fix that, the positioning of text is straight forward. Hope it helps!!!